# antlr4: not able to match single word

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm a newbie to antlr4 and trying to make a parser. However, I am stuck on the most basic step of parsing a single word.

My grammar looks like:

```
grammar test;

program : WORD EOF;

WORD : 'test';
```

And my input file looks like:

```
test
```

The input file is only one line, has no trailing spaces. If I open it in a hex-editor it shows as 5 bytes: `test<EOF>`.

From what I understand of antlr, this rule should match a WORD token then an EOF token then stop parsing. However, I get `line 1:4 missing 'test' at '<EOF>'` when parsing the file.

I've worked with lex/yacc before and not encountered an error like this. I understand that antlr works differently, so I am curious why I am encountering this error.

Comment: Let your lexer print the tokens it recognized. That should always be the first step in cases like this.

Comment: Try removing the control-d character, or whatever the fifth character is, in the input, now with 4 chars and rerun. EOF in Antlr is not a character, but a synthesized token created when it runs out of input.

Comment: To encode an actual EOF (control-d) in an Antlr grammar that is in a file, you must use the Unicode to represent that character. `grammar G; program: 'test' '\u0004' EOF;`. Depending on which runtime method you called, the file encoding is UTF-8. https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/4b649103f31e0c0bc3bd0bb964efd0dea6b9f5a0/runtime/CSharp/src/CharStreams.cs#L30

Comment: Thanks for the help. To answer your questions: yes this is truly my entire grammar. Also, perhaps I was not clear enough, the file only consists of "test", I can't get rid of the actual EOF character in the file.

The real problem was not my antlr grammar however. I was calling `parser.program()` twice which I suspect was causing antlr to look for "test" after the EOF.

Comment: Yep. I've done that too--double call to the parser (without a rewind of the input).